# How to plot vectorized mathematical expression function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have developed a code for vectorized function and tried to plot the function but it's not showing me the result.
()=(−1)

I have imported the required libraries in this code, at  =1  the value of the function is 0. Also at  =1.1  the value is just a bit above 0.1. This implies that the derivative of the function at  =1  is a bit above  1

```
# display plot of function for indicated range here.  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pylab import ylim
x = 5
def f(x):
    return x * (x - 1)
f(x)
y = f(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ylim(0.9,1.1)
plt.plot(y)
plt.title('Vectorized function plot')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
```

Need help to understand this problem.

Comment: define your function as `def f(x):
    return x * (x - 1) if isinstance(x,(int,float)) else [i*(i-1) for i in x]` then use many points eg: `x = range(-10,40)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways to fix this code. In every case, you have to remove (or comment out) line

```
ylim(0.9,1.1)
```

Because your f(5) = 20 and you are asking to restrict the y-axis to 0.9 to 1.1

**Method 1: plot using symbol 'o' **

```
# display plot of function for indicated range here.  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

from pylab import ylim

x=5

def f(x):
    return x * (x - 1)
f(x)
y = f(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
#  ~ ylim(0.9,1.1)
plt.plot(y, 'o')
plt.title('Vectorized function plot')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Method 2: use multiple values for x**

```
# display plot of function for indicated range here.  
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

from pylab import ylim

# x ranges from 5 to 7
x = np.arange(5,7+1)


def f(x):
    return x * (x - 1)
f(x)
y = f(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
#  ~ ylim(0.9,1.1)
plt.plot(y, 'o-')
plt.title('Vectorized function plot')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @bfirs Thank you for your explanation for some reason my points are not connected by a line. Why is it so?

Comment: @bfirs Never mind. I just figured it out. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You are plotting a single point. Single points or invisible unless you use markers.

Plot several points: e.g. `x = np.array([5,6])`

Use markers: e.g. `plt.plot(x, y, 'o')`

Also note you probably want to specify your `x` values when plotting. And also you force `ylim` to useless values: at `x=5` , `f(x) = 20`. but you are plotting `[0.9, 1.1]`.

You talk about the derivative but none of your code is about derivatives...

Comment: I'm a beginner in Jupiter notebook. That's why my code is not in proper shape. Can you help me to write this code?

Comment: @Mayur. If this answer is not helpful to you, I'd say you need a basic python tutorial, not stack overflow